# How do I put an argument into the BROWSER variable?

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables, alias

I like to be able to do `export BROWSER="lynx -cfg=~/.lynx.cfg"`. I tried this directly, and I also tried setting an alias `alias lynx="lynx -cfg=~/.lynx.cfg"`, but these didn't work. (Meaning that tools that use this variable to launch a browser still ignored my config file or didn't launch the browser at all.)

Comment: Does it work if you rename your configuration file into `~/.lynxrc` and don't use an option?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, it doesn't work. It seems to be using another default config file.

Comment: How/where did you set the alias?; How did you try to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$BROWSER` is understood by several utilities as being your web browser of choice.

Depending on the utility, it will be expected to contain:

1. the path or name of the executable
2. a list of words the first of which is the path or name and the other ones a list of initial arguments. If you're lucky, it will also understand some form of quoting similar to what shells do.
3. (very unlikely and it would be a very unwise thing to do) the start of a shell command line.

If you were in the first case, I'd expect the utility you tried it in to complain about an unexisting `"lynx -cfg=~/.lynx.cfg"` command.

In the third case, note that shells don't expand the `~` in `-cfg=~/.lynx.cfg`. `zsh` only does it when the `magicequalsubst` option is enabled. `bash` only expands a `~` after a `=` if what's on the left of `=` looks like a valid variable name and it's not in POSIX mode.

However `lynx` (at least version 2.8.9dev.16 on my system) does appear to understand `~` as meaning one's home directory by itself, so I'd expect yours to work for utilities in the second and third category.

```
$ BROWSER='echo -cfg=~' sensible-browser foo
-cfg=~ foo
```

So either your browser is of a *fourth* category that ignores anything but the first word or only takes a hint as to what your browser is; or your version of `lynx` doesn't understand `~` as meaning home.

Run your utility as `strace -fe execve the-utility` to see what it tries to execute.

In the case of your versions of `lynx` not treating `~` as home, you can define `$BROWSER` as:

```
export BROWSER="lynx -cfg=$HOME/.lynx.cfg"
```

(assuming `$HOME` doesn't contain blanks or quotes (or other characters special to a shell))

In any case, you should be able to define `$BROWSER` as a script that passes the correct parameters to `lynx`, like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec lynx -cfg="$HOME/.lynx.cfg" "$@"
```

and use that as your `$BROWSER`.

<sup>Incidentally, if your `$HOME` started with `~` characters, that would fool `lynx`, which is why it's not such a good idea for `lynx` to handle those `~` by itself.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can however you could try:

Must use absolute path.

```
export BROWSER='/home/username/lynx.sh'
```

Create new file lynx.sh in home dir.

```
#!/bin/bash
linx -cfg=/home/username/.lynx.cfg
```

Make it exicutable.

Then:

```
Launching Browser should launch lynx.
or
./lynx.sh
```

And/Or:

Type:

```
whereis lynx
```

Use in next step.

Edit bash_aliases:

Must use absolute path to: lynx.cfg

Must use absolute path to: lynx, if not in /usr/bin/

```
alias=lynx='/path/to/lynx -cfg=/home/username/.lynx.cfg'
```

Must use ' ' if path contains special charactors.

Comment: I thought of the first solution and was going to post it but you beat me to it :)) I don’t understand the second solution though? How is this different from a normal alias, which I tried and it didn’t work?

Comment: Forgot must use absolute path..

Comment: The second solution doesn't work on zsh.

Comment: The first solution makes the tool that is using BROWSER hang, though only after adding "$@" to the end of your script. Without this change, the tool just exits after a few seconds. I tried echoing hi in the script, and it was not echoed back to me when I ran the tool. (I am running `ddgr --unsafe -n 6  --noprompt '!w apple'` if it helps.)